# Use of annotation in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf-2

When we use annotations in Beans, does the framework use Reflection to recognize the scope?
What is the flow of the above process?
Right from page being called to bean getting instantiated and being put into concerned sessionMap ,applicationMap or requestMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When we use annotations in Beans, does the framework use Reflection to recognize the scope?*

That's correct.

---

> *What is the flow of the above process? Right from page being called to bean getting instantiated and being put into concerned sessionMap ,applicationMap or requestMap?*

At that point, the annotations are not been processed. They are processed only once during JSF startup and remembered in server's memory. JSF just ends up with a collection of all registered managed beans which is then further used during runtime. Based on a managed bean name, JSF already knows the class and the scope. Simply put, when a given managed bean cannot be found in the scope, JSF will do a `Class#newInstance()` on it and put it in the desired scope.

Comment: As always Thanks for the explanation.